# Is there a way to undo split-window-below in emacs?

Tags: emacs

If I have my frame split horizontally, then split one of those widows vertically with split-window-below, is there a way to go back to 2 windows split horizontally without having to use delete-other-windows and then split-window-right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `delete-window` which is bound to `C-x 0`.

Comment: You can replace the 0 with another integer to delete different windows other than the leftmost one.

Answer (score 20):

If you enable `winner-mode`, you get something akin to a stack-based undo/redo functionality for all your window configuration changes. By default, `C-c <left>` gets bound to `winner-undo`, while `C-c <right>` performs `winner-redo`.

Comment: `winner-mode` is great! Unfortunately it will revert other windows if you've changed them since you were in the previous config. Just found out that there's a `delete-window` (`C-x 0`) which is a bit simpler for getting rid of just the unwanted window.

Comment: @banjomonster, yeah, it's admittedly not necessarily the right solution if all you need to do is one targeted window delete.

Answer (score 12):

You can save your window-configurations:

**window-configuration-to-register** *C-x r w*

and restore it later:

**jump-to-register** *C-x r j*

using [registers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Registers.html)