# Undo view/perspective

Tags: eclipse, perspective

I did a mistake: I don't know how, but I moved many views from tabs to others. (for instance, "package explorer" is in the right-side instead of left, ...)

**Do you know if I can do an "undo" (like a `ctrl-z` or [winner-undo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11106956/2321793) for emacs) to come back in a previous view/perspective configuration ?**

*precision : I don't want to reset the layout to a default perspective.*

Comment: Had to delete my answer after your clarification. As far as I know, unless you saved your perspective, you can't just go back.

Comment: Without resetting the perspective or manually rearranging tabs, I mean

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no 'undo' for view move, but you can select the tabs and drag them wherever you want in the perspective (except in the editors area).